# Dealing with pagination in web pages while using jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, jsoup

I have been using jsoup to crawl through webpages of a particular website.
Basically i am trying to extract all the href's that have a link of a pdf.
I have been successful in getting all the link of a particular page . But there are 10 such pages. The web pages uses a logic of javascript _doPostBack() function to navigate to other pages. How do i get this done by jsoup.

This is how i am trying it right now

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(" some website name")
                        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", __EVENTARGUMENT)
                        .data("__EVENTTARGET", __EVENTTARGET)
                        .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", __EVENTVALIDATION)
                        .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR ", __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR)
                        .cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", sessionId)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .timeout(0)
                        .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .post();
```

But i am getting a false url output.
I have defined all the variables before sending.

Answer (score 0):

When I hit this kind of problem, here how I solve them:

- Load the page in a browser
- Spy the http messages exchanged between the browser and the server while going through the pages (Fiddler, Firebug, Dev Console/Toolbar ...)
- Identify every single bytes browser and server exchange (headers, cookies etc)
- Once ALL single bytes identified try to go through the pages with [hurl.it](http://hurl.it) (enter headers, cookies, user-agent etc)
- Once you succeed going through pages with hurl.it, instruct Jsoup to do the same

Comment: Not much of a help :(

Comment: @darkHorse what is the website to try to scrap?

Comment: @darkHorse Some data are missing in the code of your post: __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED, __EVENTVALIDATION, ctl00$TopMenu$srch. You may need to add the `Referer` header too...

Comment: Thanks @Stephan . I inspected all the elements being sent through firebug. And sent it through java code